# Пересобрать массив в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите пересобрать массив в новый вид, количество значений не ведомо как и количество ключей

Оригинальной массив

```
Array(
    [color] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gray
            [1] => Blue
            ...
        )

    [size] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            ...
        )
    ...
)
```

должно получиться

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Blue
            [1] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gray
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gray
            [1] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Gray
            [1] => 3
        )
    ...
)
```

Comment: А как понять что должно быть на выходе, если ключей и значений может быть сколько угодно? Если будет ещё 3й ключ `date` и там будет 10 значений? Что должно быть?

Comment: Добавится еще одно поле которое должно браться рекурсивно, тобто на выходе должно быть столько итераций сколько имеет наибольший массив + у всех должно клонировать значение

Comment: Ярослав да будет ещё 10 значений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Верный ответ

```
/**
 * @param  array  $array
 *
 * @return array
 *
 * @author wfoojjaec.eu.org
 */
function arrayGenerator(array $array): array
{
    //  Считаем количество записей по каждому именному ключу
    $count = array_map('count', $array);
    //  Считаем общее количество записей в результате
    $product = array_product($count);
    //  Обнуляем счётчики для чередования значений
    $keys = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), 0);
    //  Делаем буфер для результата
    $result = [];
    for ($offset = 0; $offset < $product; $offset++) {
        //  Делаем буфер для значения
        $value = [];
        foreach ($keys as $key => &$index) {
            //  Собираем значение по текущим счётчикам
            $value[$key] = $array[$key][$index];
            //  Смещаем счётчики
            $index = $index === $count[$key] - 1 ? 0 : $index + 1;
        }
        //  Записываем готовое значение
        $result[] = array_values($value);
    }
    //  Получаем массив, в котором попеременно чередуются все возможные комбинации
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Если добавить третий цвет, то получатся повторы, а не комбинации

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "color" => array("Gray","Blue"),
    "size" => array(1,2,3,4,5)
);
// В функицю подаем исходный массив вернет пересобраный
function foo($array_p)
{
    $array2 = array();
    foreach ($array_p["color"] as $value_color) {

        foreach ($array_p["size"] as $value_size) {
            $vrem = array();
            array_push($vrem, $value_color, $value_size);
            array_push($array2, $vrem);
        }
    }
    return $array2;
}


var_dump(foo($array));
```

---

1. Функция выбрала
   array(10) {
2. [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Gray" [1]=> int(1) }
3. [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Gray" [1]=> int(2) }
4. [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Gray" [1]=> int(3) }
5. [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Gray" [1]=> int(4) }
6. [4]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Gray" [1]=> int(5) }
7. [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Blue" [1]=> int(1) }
8. [6]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Blue" [1]=> int(2) }
9. [7]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Blue" [1]=> int(3) }
10. [8]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Blue" [1]=> int(4) }
11. [9]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Blue" [1]=> int(5) } }

Comment: Нет этот вариант мне не подходит так как массив может быть больше в матрице например 5х5х10. Снизу скинул верный ответ